# Error in creating view in mysql. while query runs correctly when independently run

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

This mysql  query runs just fine independently. But when I use this query to create a view  then `Error Code: 1064` message appears in sql yog. Please identify the reason of this error.

```
CREATE
VIEW `databaseName`.`viewName` 
AS
((SELECT
`tblgrn`.`InitialLabNo`
, `invlabtes`.`Code` AS LabNo 
, `invlabmaterial`.`Description` AS material 
, `invlabtessubtable`.`SrNo` 
, `invlabtessubtable`.`Result` 
,COALESCE(NULL, 'Verified') AS TYPE
    , `tblgrn`.`Comp_Code` 
    , `tblgrn`.`Unit_Code`     
   , `tblgrn`.`UserId`
FROM
`tblgrn`
INNER JOIN `invlabtes` 
    ON (`tblgrn`.`InitialLabNo` = `invlabtes`.`Code`)
INNER JOIN `invlabtessubtable` 
    ON (`invlabtes`.`Code` = `invlabtessubtable`.`Code`)
INNER JOIN `invlabmaterial` 
    ON (`invlabtessubtable`.`TestCode` = `invlabmaterial`.`Code`))
UNION
 (SELECT
`tblgrn`.`InitialLabNo`
, `invlabtesscale`.`Code`  AS LabNo
, `invlabmaterial`.`Description`
, `invlabscalesubtable`.`SrNo`
, `invlabscalesubtable`.`Result`
,COALESCE(NULL, 'Running') AS TYPE
    , `tblgrn`.`Comp_Code` 
   , `tblgrn`.`Unit_Code`     
    , `tblgrn`.`UserId`
  FROM
`tblgrn`
INNER JOIN `invlabtesscale` 
    ON (`tblgrn`.`InitialLabNo` = `invlabtesscale`.`IniLabNo`)
INNER JOIN `invlabscalesubtable` 
    ON (`invlabtesscale`.`Code` = `invlabscalesubtable`.`Code`)
INNER JOIN `invlabmaterial` 
    ON (`invlabscalesubtable`.`TestCode` = `invlabmaterial`.`Code`)));
```

this is the error message:

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION
     SELECT
         `tblgrn`.`InitialLabNo`
        , `invlabtesscale`.`Code`  AS LabNo' at line 22

Execution Time : 0 sec
   Transfer Time  : 0 sec
   Total Time     : 0.018 sec

Comment: This error usually points to a place in the syntax where the error occurs.  Can you include the complete error message?

Comment: i have included the error message in question now. plz check it @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0):

Remove the bracket between UNION and SELECT.

```
UNION
 (SELECT
```

should be

```
UNION
 SELECT
```

You may need to remove the closing bracket too.

Comment: I have removed bracket between union and select and corresponding closing bracket too in both (first and second part) of the query . But still there is some error

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Donal . . . Remove all the parentheses around both subqueries.

Comment: Views are not available in earlier versions of MySQL. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/views.html

Comment: I am using `5.5.33-31.1` version. And Even after removing all parentheses around both sub queries, the error still appears